# Adding new function to jQuery prototype using fat arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

There are plenty of questions about ECMAScript 6 fat arrows or extending jQuery's prototype, but I have found none which explains how they work together with an example.

Not using fat arrows, I usually do this to create a new function for use with jQuery, for instance:

```
$.fn.populate = function (items /*read from .json*/) {

    console.log(items); //JS object passed as param
    console.log(self); //Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}
    console.log(this); //jQuery object with $('#populate-me')

    $this = $(this);
    Object.entries(items).forEach(function (pair) {
        $this.append('<div>' + pair[0] + ' - ' + pair[1] + '</div>');
    });
};

//usage
$('#populate-me').populate(items);
```

Is ther a way of doing that WITH fat arrows? Like, say:

```
$.fn.populate = (items /*read from .json*/, maybe) => {

    console.log(items); //JS object passed as param
    console.log(maybe); //undefined
    console.log(self); //Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}
    console.log(this); //Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}

    $this = $(SOMETHING TO ACCESS #populate-me);
    Object.entries(items).forEach(function (pair) {
        $this.append('<div>' + pair[0] + ' - ' + pair[1] + '</div>');
    });
};
```

or should I stick to non-fat-arrow functions?

thanx

Comment: Not possible like that because `this` will be inherited from the outer scope, rather than being taken from the calling context. Ugly way to do it would be to explicitly pass the collection in an argument

Comment: @CertainPerformance; what do you mean by "the collection"?

Comment: The jQuery collection. eg `$('div')` is a jQuery collection of `<div>`s

Comment: @CertainPerformance; do you mean `$('#populate-me').populate(items, $('#populate-me'));`?? ugly would fall short

Comment: `const $populateme = $('#populate-me'); $populateme.populate(items, $populateme)` Pass the calling context manually, don't duplicate the collection again. (bad idea either way, just use a regular function instead)